# How to enumerate through Colors in WinRT?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime

Enumerating through colors in non-WinRT is a common question with a simple answer. But, since the Colors 'ENUM' is actually just a class with static 'color' properties you can't use the standard approach in WinRT.

How do you enumerate colors in WinRT?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Like this:

Enumerating through Colors in WinRT requires `using System.Reflection` so you can fetch the static properties sub-classed in the container class 'Colors'. Like this:

```
Dictionary<string, Windows.UI.Color> Colors()
{
    var _Colors = typeof(Windows.UI.Colors)
        // using System.Reflection;
        .GetRuntimeProperties()
        .Select(c => new
        {
            Color = (Windows.UI.Color)c.GetValue(null),
            Name = c.Name
        });
    return _Colors.ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.Color);
}
```

Source: http://codepaste.net/j3mzrw

Note: if you don't like reflection (for some reason) then there's nothing stopping you from hand coding an enumerable of the colors, too. Creating a 'dynamic' list of colors is really just fancy for fancy sake - colors don't get updated. Just write the list!

**Here, I did it for you:**

```
public class ColorList : List<Windows.UI.Color>
{
    public ColorList()
    {
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.AliceBlue);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.AntiqueWhite);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.Aqua);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.Aquamarine);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.Azure);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.Beige);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.Bisque);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.Black);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.BlanchedAlmond);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.Blue);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.BlueViolet);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.Brown);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.BurlyWood);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.CadetBlue);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.Chartreuse);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.Chocolate);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.Coral);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.CornflowerBlue);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.Cornsilk);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.Crimson);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.Cyan);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.DarkBlue);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.DarkCyan);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.DarkGoldenrod);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.DarkGray);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.DarkGreen);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.DarkKhaki);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.DarkMagenta);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.DarkOliveGreen);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.DarkOrange);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.DarkOrchid);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.DarkRed);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.DarkSalmon);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.DarkSeaGreen);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.DarkSlateBlue);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.DarkSlateGray);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.DarkTurquoise);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.DarkViolet);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.DeepPink);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.DeepSkyBlue);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.DimGray);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.DodgerBlue);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.Firebrick);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.FloralWhite);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.ForestGreen);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.Fuchsia);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.Gainsboro);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.GhostWhite);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.Gold);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.Goldenrod);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.Gray);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.Green);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.GreenYellow);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.Honeydew);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.HotPink);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.IndianRed);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.Indigo);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.Ivory);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.Khaki);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.Lavender);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.LavenderBlush);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.LawnGreen);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.LemonChiffon);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.LightBlue);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.LightCoral);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.LightCyan);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.LightGoldenrodYellow);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.LightGray);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.LightGreen);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.LightPink);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.LightSalmon);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.LightSeaGreen);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.LightSkyBlue);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.LightSlateGray);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.LightSteelBlue);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.LightYellow);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.Lime);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.LimeGreen);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.Linen);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.Magenta);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.Maroon);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.MediumAquamarine);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.MediumBlue);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.MediumOrchid);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.MediumPurple);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.MediumSeaGreen);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.MediumSlateBlue);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.MediumSpringGreen);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.MediumTurquoise);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.MediumVioletRed);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.MidnightBlue);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.MintCream);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.MistyRose);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.Moccasin);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.NavajoWhite);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.Navy);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.OldLace);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.Olive);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.OliveDrab);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.Orange);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.OrangeRed);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.Orchid);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.PaleGoldenrod);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.PaleGreen);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.PaleTurquoise);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.PaleVioletRed);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.PapayaWhip);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.PeachPuff);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.Peru);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.Pink);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.Plum);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.PowderBlue);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.Purple);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.Red);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.RosyBrown);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.RoyalBlue);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.SaddleBrown);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.Salmon);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.SandyBrown);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.SeaGreen);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.SeaShell);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.Sienna);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.Silver);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.SkyBlue);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.SlateBlue);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.SlateGray);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.Snow);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.SpringGreen);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.SteelBlue);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.Tan);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.Teal);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.Thistle);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.Tomato);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.Transparent);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.Turquoise);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.Violet);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.Wheat);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.White);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.WhiteSmoke);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.Yellow);
        this.Add(Windows.UI.Colors.YellowGreen);
    }
}
```

Either works.