# How to parse an HTML color name to a SolidColorBrush in a Windows Store App

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

In .NET there is a class to cast a text HTML colour name to a Color (in this case "Red"):

```
Color col=(Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("Red"); 
Brush brush=new SolidColorBrush(col);
```

(Which I took from here: [Cast Color Name to SolidColorBrush](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9276813/cast-color-name-to-solidcolorbrush))

This works for pretty much [all the colours that can be found on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11_color_names)

Is there an equivalent class/library for `Windows Store Apps` that can do the same thing?

Comment: I don't know much about *windows-store-app* . Isn't this available `var color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("red");`

Comment: No unfortunately it isn't ... or at least it is not in the same namespace.

Comment: If you're doing it frequently, you might just want to build and cache a dictionary like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12751008/how-to-enumerate-through-colors-in-winrt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
using System.Reflection;

public SolidColorBrush ColorStringToBrush(string name)
{
    var property = typeof(Colors).GetRuntimeProperty(name);
    if (property != null)
    {
        return new SolidColorBrush((Color)property.GetValue(null));
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI - `GetRuntimeProperty` doesn't exist in WinRT.

Comment: [It exists](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13197768/1230188). You need to manually write `using System.Reflection;` on top of cs file.

Comment: Ahh. It's an extension method. :)